# How to persist an object-model to JSON and serialize a dictionary as its array of values?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-serialization

```
public class Portfolio
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public Dictionary<string,Position> Positions {get; set;}
}

public class Position
{
    public string Ticker {get; set;}
    public decimal Size {get; set;}
}

JsonConvert.SerializeObject(portfolio);
```

will produce for example :

```
{
  "Name": "SP500",
  "Positions": {
        "AOS": {
          "Ticker": "AOS",
          "Size": 100,
        },
        "ABT": {
          "Ticker": "ABT",
          "Size": 100,
        }
    }
}
```

But I'd like to minimize space and store the positions as an array :

```
{
  "Name": "SP500",
  "Positions": 
  [
      {
        "Ticker": "AOS",
        "Size": 100,
      },
      {
        "Ticker": "ABT",
        "Size": 100,
      }
  ]
}
```

How to save and load this json into my object model ?

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
public class Portfolio
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public List<Position> Positions {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use `List` I want to use `Dictionary` as stated in my question

Answer (score 1):

You could add a [custom `JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) for `Dictionary<string,Position>` that serializes the dictionary values as a list. The converter assumes that the dictionary key can be extracted somehow from the dictionary value during deserialization.

First, define the following converter:

```
public class PositionDictionaryConverter : DictionaryAsValueListConverter<Position>
{
    protected override string GetKey(Position position) { return position.Ticker; }
}

public abstract class DictionaryAsValueListConverter<TValue> : JsonConverter
{
    protected abstract string GetKey(TValue value);

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(Dictionary<string, TValue>).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.MoveToContent().TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        var list = serializer.Deserialize<List<TValue>>(reader);
        var dictionary = (IDictionary<string, TValue>)(existingValue ?? serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType).DefaultCreator());
        foreach (var item in list)
            dictionary.Add(GetKey(item), item);
        return dictionary;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, ((IDictionary<string, TValue>)value).Values);
    }
}

public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JsonReader MoveToContent(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.None)
            reader.Read();
        while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment && reader.Read())
            ;
        return reader;
    }
}
```

Then apply it to your model as follows:

```
public class Portfolio
{
    public string Name {get; set;}

    [JsonConverter(typeof(PositionDictionaryConverter))]
    public Dictionary<string,Position> Positions {get; set;}
}
```

Or, use it in settings as follows:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = { new PositionDictionaryConverter() },
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, settings);
```

Of course the converter assumes that the dictionary key and ticker name are identical.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xUiysd).

Answer (score 0):

You can change your model to :

```
public class Portfolio
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public List<Position> Positions {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use `List` I want to use `Dictionary` as stated in my question

Comment: *"as stated in my question"* Where ?

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything wrong with just changing your object model for Portfolio to the below?  I think this would serialize how you would like.  You'd probably have to use LINQ to find the object you want in the List.  This is also assuming there will always be unique Ticker

```
public class Portfolio
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public List<Position> Positions {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use `List` I want to use `Dictionary` as stated in my question

Answer (score 0):

Easily the simplest option will be to write a separate model which is used for serialization purposes:

Classes:

```cs
public class Portfolio
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Position> Positions { get; set; }
}

//this is a class used just for serialization
public class PortfolioForSerialization
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Position[] Positions { get; set; }
}

public class Position
{
    public string Ticker { get; set; }
    public decimal Size { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
//The portfolio class you want to work with (dictionary property)
var portfolio = new Portfolio()
{
    Name = "MyPortfolio",
    Positions = new Dictionary<string, UserQuery.Position>()
    {
        { "AOS", new Position() { Size = 10, Ticker = "AOS"}},
        { "ABT", new Position() { Size = 100, Ticker = "ABT"}}
    }
};
//Only used for serialization
var forSerialization = new PortfolioForSerialization()
{
    Name = portfolio.Name,
    Positions = portfolio.Positions.Select(p => p.Value).ToArray()
};

string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(forSerialization);

//On deserialization, map the array back to a dictionary
var deserializedPortfolio = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PortfolioForSerialization>(serialized);

//Map the serialization model back to your working model
var workingPortfolio = new Portfolio()
{
    Name = deserializedPortfolio.Name,
    Positions = deserializedPortfolio.Positions.ToDictionary(k => k.Ticker, v => v)
};
```

Otherwise, you're going to need to use a [custom contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm).